# SQL case expression using nullable parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I pass a list of parameters to my stored procedure and some of them can be nullable.

Based on the values passed I need to create a where clause; What I'm trying to do is if @productType is not null then WHERE PmTyId = @productType ELSE dont add it to the where clause.

How do I achieve that?

```
WHERE 
        CASE
            WHEN @productType IS NOT NULL THEN PmTyId = @productType
        END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you don't use a `case` in a `where` clause. You can solve this with simple boolean logic

```
WHERE (@productType IS NULL OR PmTyId = @productType)
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I was trying to over complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this. Wrapping in parenthesis will allow you to add more in the `WHERE` clause;

Ok, test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (IDField int, PmTyId varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #TestData (IDField, PmTyId)
VALUES
(1,'include')
,(2,'include')
,(3,'dont include')
```

My query;

```
DECLARE @productType varchar(20); SET @productType = 'include'

SELECT
IDField
,PmTyId
FROM #TestData
WHERE (@productType IS NULL OR @productType = PmTyId)
```

Outputs;

```
IDField PmTyId
1       include
2       include
```

If @productType is set to `null` then you get these results;

```
IDField PmTyId
1       include
2       include
3       dont include
```

If you need to add further parameters then do something like this;

```
SELECT
IDField
,PmTyId
FROM #TestData
WHERE (@productType IS NULL OR @productType = PmTyId)
OR (@Parameter2 IS NULL OR @Parameter2 = Field2)
OR (@Parameter3 IS NULL OR @Parameter3 = Field3)
```

Comment: You mixed it up a bit didn't you? (Didn't down vote you)

Comment: just making some test data to see where I've gone wrong if i have, two ticks :)

Comment: HINT: `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` :)

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
WHERE ISNULL(@productType, PmTyId) = PmTyId
```